# How does this function that takes in a RequestHandler in express work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rest, express

I was browsing through some code examples for Express server on GitHub and came across this function used to wrap around REST API controllers and was confused how it works...

```
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';

export const catchErrors = (requestHandler: RequestHandler): RequestHandler => {
  return async (req, res, next): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      console.log(req.body) **// returns requestHandler's req parameter //**

      return await requestHandler(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

It is used to wrap around REST API controllers to catch errors and pass it into an error handling middleware. A brief example of such usage would be this:

```
import {catchErrors} from './error'
export const fetchData = catchErrors(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  /// perform data fetching here ///
  return res.status(200).send()

})
```

I am confused as to how the catchErrors function works. To my understanding, requestHandler parameter refers to the original REST controller callback. However, the next part of catchError where it says
`return async (req, res, next): Promise<any> => {...}`
Where does this (req, res, next) come from? I tried console logging the `req.body` and it turned out to be the request body of the requestHandler parameter parsed above. I do not understand how the requestHandler's (req, res, next) can be referenced in this way instead of say requestHandler.req (which does not work)?

GitHub link where I found this code: https://github.com/oldboyxx/jira_clone/blob/master/api/src/errors/asyncCatch.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catchErrors` is just a helper function to return a middleware function from another middleware function, enhancing or adding features. in your case, think of `fetchData` as

```js
 async (req, res, next): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      console.log(req.body) **// returns requestHandler's req parameter //**

      const fetchFunction = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
           /// perform data fetching here ///
           return res.status(200).send()

      }
      return await fetchFunction(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

which is a valid middleware for express. take a look at [higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) which are the same concept.